# .iso for installing latest version of SilverLight?

Tags: silverlight, installation

is there any **.iso** file available for installing `silverlight` **[for developing silverlight Application not for running application]?**

so i can install it when i am offline also.

i have just downloaded [.iso file of VS2010Express](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/en-us/products/2010-editions/express-iso) but it doesn't comes with `SilverLight`?

Please help.

Comment: What exactly do you mean? The runtime or the Visual Studio Tools?

Comment: tool for developing silverlight applicaiton

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you looking for this installer? http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=18149

After the installation you will get new project types for silverlight
[image]

Comment: I have downloaded and install it..but it doesn't show any thing in File=>New=>Project......how to create new project ...i can't understand?

Comment: thank you so much for answering...now i have install Visual web Developer Express 2010...and it works fine......BTW,,Screen shot you have provided is which version of VS2010? i mean Express,Professional or Ultimate etc....

Comment: I use the Ultimate version of VS2010.

Comment: does it free or cost you? please tell me